# Ajax call returning HTTP 302

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When we make this ajax call, intermittently I get HTTP status code as 302. While most of the times, the ajax call is successful as well returning HTTP status as 200 OK. I am unable to get the exact reason for this and how to overcome this scenario.
The HTTP status 302 is returned in particular scenario when I leave the application idle for 10-15 minutes and then make this call. 
However when I hit the URL directly in browser the correct data is returned.
Please advice.

```
function checkProgressStatus(event){            
     $.ajax({
             url: "/"+window.AppContext+"/servlet/Progress",
             cache: false,
             dataType: 'json',
             async:false,
             success: function(data,ev){ 
                 if(data.Progress == 'INPROGRESS'){                     
                    alert("Execution in progress");
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();                       
                 }

             },
        error: function (exception) {
            alert("Request to check inprogress status failed.");
            window.open("/"+window.AppContext+"/path/filter/AnotherPage.html");
        }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Seeing the correct result in the browser does not mean that the browser did not get a `302` status. The `302` response is a temporary redirect, that means that the resource you request is temporary located under another url, and that url is passed with the response. The browser will automatically redirect to that url.

Comment: This website can check for you if your url is redirected: www.redirect-checker.org

Comment: There are currently no redirects at the code level or server level. All we are doing is to fetch the value of a string from the servlet by hitting this url. The only redirect is in the error block but ideally it shouldn't be lending in the error block.